# Send email to customer from shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, email-templates, shopping-cart

Hi I need some help I like to have one button in shopping cart that when it will be clicked it will send all products that are added in shopping cart with any email like new order email can this be done or there already exist any extension

Comment: I only have tried to see how works abandoned cart from mailchimp

Comment: So this question is quite broad. I'll give you a path, implement it, if you have a problem somewhere ask a new question. But maybe there is someone who will give you a complete solution. don't bet on it.

Comment: Found simple and affordable extension
https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Implement a new controller to do all this
2. Add a new block, template and add a layout.xml to add the button into the cart page
3. on click on the button you fire a request to the new controller
4. get the quote Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
5. send a new mail, add all the products to the mail_template

Comment: You are welcome, good luck with this!

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Does this approach work correctly in Magento 1.8 as we have formKey concept in Magento 1.8.

Comment: yes, theoretically. If you check for the form key it will be used, if you don't check for it, it works as intended